# How do I interpret X-program backtrace report?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm playing with X-development. I've got a basic proto-WM going that works for a while and then produces these errors after a fairly random time.

[edit]

```
Locking assertion failure.  Backtrace:
#0 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0 [0x7f71dcf9a9ac]
#1 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0(xcb_xlib_unlock+0x24) [0x7f71dcf9aa54]
#2 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 [0x7f71ddefe340]
#3 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6(XAllocColor+0xc1) [0x7f71ddedada1]
#4 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x408e0b]
#5 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x409062]
#6 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x407a9d]
#7 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x406c6d]
#8 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x402734]
#9 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x407e37]
#10 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x407304]
#11 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x407335]
#12 /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0x7f71ddc9afc7]
#13 /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f71dd26a59d]
Locking assertion failure.  Backtrace:
#0 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0 [0x7f71dcf9a9ac]
#1 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0(xcb_xlib_lock+0x17) [0x7f71dcf9ab17]
#2 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 [0x7f71ddefe420]
#3 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 [0x7f71ddefeb5b]
#4 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 [0x7f71ddefeeb5]
#5 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6(XNextEvent+0x68) [0x7f71ddee5898]
#6 /home/mais/code/simplewin/bin/Debug/simplewin [0x404bc2]
#7 /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0x7f71ddc9afc7]
#8 /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f71dd26a59d]
```

It looks like some kind of synchronization bug in my app; that much of the time the resources used are released in the correct sequence, but at some stage this get mixed-up and then the error(s) occur.
How do I interpret the above to find the location/cause of the errors?

Comment: Why don't you use gdb to find out what went wrong?

Comment: @ssegvic: can you put into an answer any pointers in what I could do using gdb to try to isolate the error(s)? My edit above was the result of a superficial use, but the backtrace-output does not remain the same. Any ideas you have will be most welcome.

Comment: I was referring to what I consider the usual debugging iteration: i) build the executable with debugging info (-g, NDEBUG undefined), ii) start the program from gdb (gdb a.out, run), iii) reproduce the crash, iv) examine the source (backtrace, up, down). I mean you surely could locate the source code corresponding to the lines from your backtraces using objdump and friends, but employing gdb should be a more comfortable option. HTH

Answer (score 1):

1) build your program with debug symbold (on gcc, pass `-g` option)
2) enable core files, and once your application crashes, open it in gdb with core file, and check the backtrace
3) is your application multithreaded and using xlib? If so, you need to enable multi-threading access to the xlib functions.
4) install ddd, and run your application using that (ddd is a gui frontend for the linux debuger gdb)